# Count days based on text changes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have "issue/request date" and the "work start date" column. work starts from stage1 and ends in stage5. 
I have a status column and 5 stages named columns. Each stage named column should show the number of days taken by that stage upon text change on the status column.for example,
if status cell contains "stage1" text for 2 days then stage1 cell will show 2 and on the 3rd day if status cell contains "stage2" text then stage2 should show 1. 
[DEMO IN EXCEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpluV.jpg)

Here, i have tried using functions 
 1. `=IF(A5214="PLATING",(TODAY()-F5214)-AQ5214,((TODAY()-F5214)-AQ5214-AS5214-AT5214-AU5214))` 
 2. `=IF(A5213="PRESS",(TODAY()-F5213),AP5213)`

The first one causing a circular reference problem and the second one changes the value when condition/text is false/not matched (cell value should stay there while condition fails)

I wonder if VBA is the only solution for this? Please guide me a lightweight solution as this file contains huge data (5k rows approx).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't understand well your request but I have attached you a pictures let me know if you are looking for something like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM63R.png)

Comment: Hi,
you have taken "item id" multiple time/duplicated but in my case its unique.
another problem is while you update for stage2, stage1 value will be null since the condition would fail at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would need to be VBA.
You can use "Worksheet_Change" to run only when a change is made to the Status Column so the number of rows shouldn't impact performance.

One way this particular problem could be done is to put in columns for each stage for start date and end date (AV:AZ for start date of each stage, BA:BE for end date of each stage for example).

So when you change the value in column A, the code will check the new and old value of the status, then update the start and end dates for that stage.

A drawback of this approach is if you incorrectly select a stage, you would have to manually amend the time on each stage columns as each row only gets one chance to update the start and end dates.

Another is that to grab the old value when you change a cell in column A, I've had to use SelectionChange, which means that you have to change which cell is selected between status changes (this won't be a problem in regular use, unless you are changing the same cell from CNC, to PRESS, to PLATING etc without selecting a separate cell between changes).

I've put an extra row in to hold today's date so you can amend the ranges in VBA to suit.

The sheet is amended to look like this:
[Sheet layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc2ih.jpg)

The formula is from cell AQ3 and can be dragged across to AU3 - you can easily amend this to count the correct  number of days at the moment it is "today - start date + 1" for stages still active - you may need to adjust this.

You can hide the extra columns, BF1 is just today's date (=TODAY()) and Column BG is just for the dropdown on column A.

```
Dim oldValue


Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    oldValue = Target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim startCol As Variant
    Dim endCol As Variant
    Dim oVal As Variant
    Dim nVal As Variant

    oVal = oldValue
    nVal = Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value

    'make no changes if anything other than column A is changed
    If Not Target.Column = 1 Then
        GoTo continue
    End If

    'add end date if status is changed to finished
    If nVal = "FINISHED" Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 57) = Date
        GoTo continue
    End If

    'update end of last stage only if new value is blank
    If IsEmpty(nVal) Then
        GoTo endDate
    End If

    'find the column of the stage being changed
    startCol = Range("AV2:AZ2").Find(nVal).Column
    If Not IsEmpty(oVal) Then
        endCol = Range("BA2:BE2").Find(oVal).Column
    End If
    Set KeyCells = Range("A:A")

    'run if something in column A is changed
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
        'update the start date of new stage
        If IsEmpty(Cells(Target.Row, startCol)) Then
            Cells(Target.Row, startCol) = Date
        End If
        'update the date of the stage just ended
        If IsEmpty(endCol) Then
            GoTo continue
        End If
        If IsEmpty(Cells(Target.Row, endCol)) Then
            If IsEmpty(oVal) Then
                GoTo continue
            End If
            Cells(Target.Row, endCol) = Date
        End If
    End If
GoTo continue
endDate:
    If oVal = "FINISHED" Then
        GoTo continue
    End If
    Cells(Target.Row, Range("BA2:BE2").Find(oVal).Column) = Date
continue:
End Sub
```